# Google play advertising sdk issue

Tags: android, google-play, revmob

I was checking my developer console and I found a yellow high lighted message on the top of Application list saying : `"We have identified a potential advertising ID policy violation with your app(s) , Please review the flagged apps".`

and I can see a yellow flag on the apps list with another message saying :`"We have determined that your app uses a library or SDK (com.revmob.client) that is in violation of the Developer Program Policy. Please note that beginning Aug 1st, 2014 the Developer Program Policy requires all updates and new apps uploaded to be compliant with the advertising ID provision of the Developer Program Policy. Apps in violation may be subject to permanent removal from the Store"`

And i understood that the issue is due to an older version of revmob sdk. In my app, the revmob sdk version is 6.4.2 and the latest version available is 6.9.8

And when i searched over google regarding the same, i found few saying updating the sdk is enough and few saying remove the sdk completely.

Anyone here who faced the same issue please help me out, should i update sdk or remove it completely?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play's policies not programming

Comment: I'm having this same issue and have followed RevMob's instructions to no avail http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/android.html#advertising_id

Comment: related --> [Policy violation issue shown for library or SDK (com.google.ads, com.google.android.gms.internal)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819297/policy-violation-issue-shown-for-library-or-sdk-com-google-ads-com-google-andr)

Answer (score 0):

Try install new libs version Revmob Android SDK 7.0.0 - 2014/11/28;
http://s3.amazonaws.com/sdks/revmob-android-sdk-7.0.0.zip
It helped me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NoIdea You should read the answer a bit more closely - the link is to the new version of the library that is giving the OP problems. And the answer actually states this - "Try install new .. version"