# Policy violation issue shown for library or SDK (com.google.ads, com.google.android.gms.internal)

Tags: android, admob, privacy-policy

In my Google Developer Console, there are warnings for several apps as

> We have determined that your app uses a library or SDK (com.google,
>   com.google.ads) that is in violation of the Developer Program Policy.
>   Please note that beginning Aug 1st, 2014 the Developer Program Policy
>   requires all updates and new apps uploaded to be compliant with the
>   advertising ID provision of the Developer Program Policy. Apps in
>   violation may be subject to permanent removal from the Store.

I am using google play services library only in those apps for advertising. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: I am also getting this message....

Comment: Please let me know if you have resilvod it

Comment: I have just started to get the same warning. Was fine a few days ago. Do you have a resolution?

Comment: I am also getting the same warning. I don't use the library com.google.android.gms.internal anywhere and we don't implement Ad mob or any other ad products in our app. can someone please help?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue, not implemented any Ad network. Can someone please help how to fix this thing?

Comment: The warning removed from playstore automatically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Google technical support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry that you received this message, it was sent out in error. Source: I am one of the software developers who worked on this.

Developers who contact Google about this will receive a reply like:

"I understand that your app is being incorrectly flagged for Advertising ID issues. I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience and any confusion this may have caused. Please disregard the warning while we work to address the notification issue in our system."

Please make sure you only ignore this message if it lists Google libraries. You might still be using non-compliant third-party libraries if those are listed.

Comment: I didn't receive an email but in the developer console I see: "    Policy Violation

    We have determined that your app uses a library or SDK (com.google.ads) that is in violation of the Developer Programme Policy. Please note that beginning 1 Aug 2014 the Developer Programme Policy requires all updates and new apps uploaded to be compliant with the advertising ID provision of the Developer Programme Policy. Apps in violation may be subject to permanent removal from the Store. Learn more."  Is this the same issue?

Comment: Yep, same thing. I changed my wording from email to message in my answer.

Comment: The warning removed from playstore automatically. Thank you Sebastian Porst

Answer (score 0):

Your app may be rejected if google doesn't approve of one of the external libraries that you use or how you use it.

In this [link](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) at the bottom there is a warning about terms violation; so even if you don't need some permissions to run the code you might need to add them to be in compliance with their T&C.

Comment: You seem to be overlooking that the libraries in question come from Google itself - that's really what makes the question interesting.

Comment: Do you know what to do in this case? I have admob account and implemented sdk jar provided by the admob for ad. and its a educational app.

Comment: It was a bug from Google. They fixed it now. Thank you for your help